# I am trying to declare getTemp variable global so that i can use it in other function. VUE.JS

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I am trying to declare getTemp variable global so that i can  use it in other function. VUE.JS

```
var weather = new Vue({
    el: '#weather',

    data: {
        getTemp: []
    },

    created: function () {
        this.fetchData();
    },        

    methods: {
        fetchData: function () {
            this.$http.get('https://vt')
                      .then(response => {
                         this.getTemp = response.data;

                      })
        }
    },
})
;
```

Comment: Do you mean other components?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Root instance `data` properties are accessible throughout the app with `this.$root.variableName`:

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    getTemp: 'Hello World!'
  },
  components: {
    'child1': {
      template: `<div><p>child1, getTemp: {{ $root.getTemp }}</p>
       <subchild></subchild>
      </div>`,
      components: {
        'subchild': {
          template: `<span>Subchild test: {{ $root.getTemp }}</span>`
        }
      }
    },
    'child2': {
      template: `<p>child2, getTemp: {{ $root.getTemp }}</p>`
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <child1></child1>
  <child2></child2>
</div>
```